# Increase the unit price in the products table of all rows with a current unit price between $5.00 and $10.00 by 5%

Tags: sql, between

Okay so I'm doing some homework and here is the question I'm struggling with:

Using the UPDATE statement, increate the unit_price in the products table of all rows with a current unit_price between $5.00 and $10.00 by 5%.

My answer to this is:

```
UPDATE      products
SET         unit_price = unit_price*1.05
WHERE       unit_price BETWEEN 5.00 AND 10.00;
GO
```

But I'm getting this error message:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'reorder_level' to data type int.

Which makes no sense as the column 'reorder_level' is int already and has nothing to do with this sql statement. Am I writing the statement incorrectly? Help!

Comment: Assuming `products` is not a view, then you are probably running some other SQL statements along with this one.

Comment: I am selecting and executing only the current statement.

Comment: This UPDATE is 100% correct. What is `products`? Is it a table or a view? Does it have any triggers? I suspect you have an ON UPDATE trigger failing

Comment: The error you report is impossible given the input you claim.  You are definitely executing some SQL outside this query.

Comment: TheSmose, you are correct but, as ean5533 points out, he may not be executing it explicitly.

Comment: Products is a table, yes. It has no triggers yet. Perhaps I will have to delete the current database and try again?

Comment: I have deleted the database and recreated it all... and the same error is popping up. I'll bring it to the attention of my teacher tonight.

Comment: Can you show the DDL you used to create the table and let us know what kind of database it is?

Comment: Your query looks fine. I have never seen an issue like this that was not the result of a trigger or calculated field. Please post the table creation script you used to create the table.

Comment: Maybe a trigger on the products table that does something wrong?

Comment: It's fine, I have class tonight so I'm sure my teacher will help me sort it out.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the error message says nothing about the *column* `reorder_level`. It says the issue is with the **value** `'reorder_level'`. Although it still seems irrelevant to the posted query, because it's about conversion to *`int`* and there's no `int`s in your query.

Comment: I asked my teacher about this error and we couldn't figure it out. Not sure what the answer to this question is...

Comment: It could be that you have corrupted data in `reorder_level` and when you try to update the row the database is checking all values for validity (not just the one you're setting) and exploding due to bad data already there. I've seen this kind of thing before, but it's rare. The fix is to find out which row has the problem by finding the ids for all target ties and going one update at a time until you find the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     UPDATE      t1
    SET         t1.unit_price = t2.unit_price*1.05
    FROM products AS t1 INNER JOIN products AS t2 ON t1.productid = t2.productid
    WHERE       t1.unit_price BETWEEN 5.00 AND 10.00;
    GO
```